Reference request: Were GR and QM discovered too early?
I am looking for references concerning an insight about the apparent stagnation of theoretical physics. But let me first sketch the context.
For a few centuries, theoretical physics went hand in hand (or slightly ran behind) experiments. There were always unexplained observations that served as a driving force for theoretical physics. However, after the work by Einstein (and many others) and the advent of quantum mechanics and relativity theory, this story seems to have changed. Working out the implications of those theories (condensed matter physics, quantum field theory, cosmology, ...) definitely took some decades, but there has not really been anything fundamentally new (in a falsifiable/verifiable sense) ever since.
Now, I have heard and/or read a few times that some people attribute this apparent pause in the developments of theoretical physics to the fact that our current fundamental theories were 'discovered' too early, in a sense that their full power and elegance actually preceded observations for the first time in history.
Sadly, I cannot clearly recall where I picked up these statements. They might

podcasts (such as Mindscape by S. Carroll),
books, or even
research papers.

Does anyone know of references/authors for such statements?
